# Cannot run project deployed on remote server through Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, importerror, openssh

I deploy a project on a remote ssh server using Pycharm. I have mapped my local folder to the correct path in the remote server and the interpreter used is the one on the server.

When I run my project in Pycharm (deployment actually happens remotely) everything runs smoothly. But if I ssh into the machine and want to start running the project from within the machine, I get

`ImportError: No module named 'replay_buffer'`

and this applies exclusively to folders within the project (not library dependencies).

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you activate your virtual environment before running `python manage.py runserver`? And you are trying to "start running' your project you are executing `python manage.py runserver`?

Comment: Yes, I activated my environment and ... I dont get the rest of the question. The project runs fine when I run it on my remote server *from* Pycharm. If I ssh inside the server, start my environment there (same env/ im using from Pycharm) I get error messages in that the paths to my project folders are not recognized.